# Do Firebase Device Tests Run sequentially or Concurrently?

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

Im currently testing an app using Firebase physical devices and I am wondering if I test it over two or more devices (S9 and One plus) would the devices be tested sequentially or in parallel. If in parallel is there a way to change it to sequentially?

Comment: Sounds like an answer @greeble31! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They tend to run as the hardware becomes available. For a given test, there is no way for you to control that order. You can refrain from submitting test #2 until you have determined test #1 is complete.

Source: Personal experience.